# Beamer poster error

Tags: beamerposter

So I'm using `beamerthemeI6dv.sty` on ShareLaTeX the `beamer` poster template.

I keep getting this error that `\setbeamerfont{footline}{fg=white, size=\normalsize}` and `\setbeamerfont*{example title}{size=\large,series=\bf,bg=i6colorscheme1,fg=white}` have errors, but I'm not seeing what's wrong with them. ShareLaTeX says that `fg` and `bg` aren't defined, yet the lines before them which have the same variables aren't marked errors.

Also when I tried to compile, on the poster `.tex` file it says that `\begin{document}` was an error, which I also don't understand.

One more question, how can you format the poster so that it's made for a standard tri-fold poster board?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution that worked well.

The Error is in file 'beamerthemeconfposter.sty'

Basically the solution is to remove the following parameters

1. In line 33 Remove: **fg=white**
2. In line 45 Remove: **bg=i6colorscheme1,fg=white**

basically its an issue with the

> \setbeamerfont macro

Same issue is being answered here as well. [basic beamerposter example, keyval error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171710/basic-beamerposter-example-keyval-error)